# grep(POSIX) regex floating point between blank space in single line

Tags: regex, grep, posix

i need regex for grep(posix) to print only(return true) if every floating point separate by blank space in single line is valid like:

```
3.14 12 18.9
```

and not print anything (return false)
if one or more invalid floating point appear in that line between blank space like:

```
8.12 1.1.1 78
```

or

```
1..28 1.09 46
```

the floating point can appears as much as possible in that single line, as long is valid floating point separate by blank space it will return true/print by grep(posix).

currently i have regex for grep:

```
grep -E "^[[:blank:][:digit:]]*.+[[:digit:]]+$" FILE
```

it work for pattern like:

```
1.13 1 1.2.3 1. 1
```

but i don't wont pattern like 1.2.3 and 1. 1 to be match, just i need is 1.13 or 1 between blank space.

note: i just need that work single line only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([[:blank:]][0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)*$'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `([[:blank:]][0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `[[:blank:]]` - a tab or space
  - `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.